# LaTex - Extra space between words of footnotes in figure environment

Tags: latex

there is extra space between the words of the footnotes in the figure below. How can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
 \caption{Title}
 \vspace{0.3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.png}
 \vspace{4pt}
     \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        {\small \textit{Note.} Figure notes here }
    \end{tablenotes}
    
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table note tries to fill the whole line. To avoid the extra space you can add `\hfill` at the end to fill the line.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\shorttitle{subtitle}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
 \caption{Title}
 \vspace{0.3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
 \vspace{4pt}
     \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        {\small \textit{Note.} Figure notes here\hfill }
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]